# Squashing first and third commits (leaving second unsquashed)

Tags: git, git-rebase, squash

Suppose I have the following history in my repo:

```
git log --oneline    
<3rd sha1> Third commit.
<2nd sha1> Second commit.
<1st sha1> First commit.
```

How do I squash the third commit to the first one leaving the second untouched?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have done this:

1. Cleaned my current changes (stashed).
2. `git rebase -i HEAD~3`.
3. Edited to:

   pick <2nd sha1> Second commit.

   pick <1st sha1> First commit.

   squash <3rd sha1> Third commit.
4. Solved the coflict: `error: could not apply <2nd sha1>... Second commit.`.
5. `git rebase --continue`.
6. Text  editor was fired with the second commit message, I kept it.
7. Solved the coflict: `error: could not apply <1nd sha1>... First commit.`.
8. `git rebase --continue`.
9. Text  editor was fired with the first commit message, I kept it.
10. Text editor was fired asking for a commit message for squashing the first and third commit, I typed a new message (`First commit (squashed).`).

Then it was done.

`git log --oneline`:

```
git log --oneline    
<2nd sha1> Second commit.
<1st sha1> First commit (squashed).
```

I managed to do it successfully, the conflicts that occurred was supposed to happen and was easy to solve.

I am pretty satisfied with the result, but I would like to know anyway if there is any better way do achieve this.